# Rails 3: class not recognized for form collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a nested form with the following field:

```
<%= f.label :size %><br />
<%= f.collection_select :size, Video::SIZE, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true, :class => "sizefield" %>
```

As you can see, I've assigned the class, "sizefield", to this field, but for some reason, my app is not recognizing it. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should post the error message and backtrace from the error you're received, and the code that the backtrace references.

Comment: there's no error. any behaviors I assign to this class have no effect.

Comment: Oh, so the CSS is messing up? I bet I know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails functions that allow two terminal hashes get confused if you don't specify the boundaries of those hashes exactly. For example:

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

You're not separating the `options` from the `html_options`. Try this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :size, Video::SIZE, :to_s, :to_s, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => "sizefield"} %>
```